# PhoneGap CLI serve commands not working

Tags: phonegap

When I try to start my PhoneGap by

```
phonegap serve
```

nothing happens.

[image]

Please help me. Where is the problem?

Comment: I have the same issue after update to 7.1.0. - macOS. The PhoneGap app (not command line) works just fine.

Comment: More info here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in 7.1.1. Version. Run `npm i -g phonegap` to update.